# Can't Center Bootstrap navigation bar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center, navigationbar

I was trying to center this: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/hwhS5/ navigation bar but no luck...

By center i mean the elements aligned in one single line in the center of the navigation... 
looked up a few solutions but none worked, resulted in a center aligned navigation bar with one element per line.

Bar html: (css & html on the jsfiddle)

```
 <div class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://chaoticunited.com/forums">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="servers.html">Servers</a></li>
        <li><a href="help.html">Help Center</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vote">Vote</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar
```

I have this: [image: i.imgur.com/JVh05N1.png]

And would like to have this:(Result from photoshop)
[image: http://i.imgur.com/B3UcOU9.png]

Comment: can you add an image with what you want it to look like.  I'm not sure I follow what you'd like.

Comment: could you show a screenshot, jsfiddle couldn't make sense properly

Comment: Also, here's a proper [Bootstrap Skeleton Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/) with the neccessary libraries being added as external resources.  You can fork it for easier development and add your code there.

Comment: I have this: http://i.imgur.com/JVh05N1.png
And would like to have this:(Result from photoshop)http://i.imgur.com/B3UcOU9.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the display value of `.navbar-nav` to inline-block and then applying `text-align` on its parent to control alignment.

If you need to change the mobile view alignment you can re-apply `text-align` at that breakpoint.

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: inline-block;
}

.navbar-default {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hwhS5/2/

Comment: i tried doing the same on a different navigation bar, same class, and it didn't worked, it only centered the dropdown contents: http://jsfiddle.net/MikeStardust/z5yyt/

Comment: I just spent 2 hours searching for the solution to this, and this was the first answer that worked. I'm surprised it doesn't have more up-votes. I can't be the only one to have this problem!

Answer (score -1):

use bootstrap class="justify-content-center"